Как скопировать первый файл для каждого расширения?
Имеется список файлов с разными типами расширений, например, ***_00.abc, ***_00.323445а, ***_00.uuu2345q и так далее, и их тысячи. Вручную могу что то пропустить
Для каждого типа расширения надо выбрать первый попавшийся файл (abc, 323445а, uuu2345q,...) и его скопировать.

Вопрос не вполне понятен. Что такое первый файл? И для каждого расширения нужно выбрать "первый" файл? Тогда сортируем файлы по расширению, а второй ключ сортировки - ваше определение "первости"

да для каждого расширения надо выбрать первый файл. Изменил тему и описание, спасибо за замечание.
есть ли возможность подсказать как это на powershell написать?

Собираем файлы из каталога, группируем по расширению, сортируем по имени, из каждой группы забираем первый файл, копируем.
$src = "c:\test" # откуда
$dst = "c:\test\copy" # куда
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $src | Group-Object -Property extension | Sort-Object -Property name | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_.Group | Select-Object -First 1
    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination "$dst\$file"
    Write-Host "File ""$file"" copied"
}


Спасибо и удачи вам уважаемый, все работает!
